# Meu while não esta parando quando a condição é verdadeira..eu digito "VITOR" mas não consigo sair do WHILE

Tags: java, eclipse, while

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RepeticaoWhile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String nome;
        
        System.out.println("Digite o nome VITOR ");
        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        nome = teclado.nextLine();
        
        while(nome!="VITOR"){
            
            System.out.println("Não entendi..digite novamente");
            nome = teclado.nextLine();
            
            }
        
        teclado.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para comparações lógicas de String em estruturas if e while a sintaxe é diferente em relação aos tipos primitivos (int, float, char...). Você poderia fazer tranquilamente:

```
while(1 != ValorDigitado) {
        System.out.println("DIGITE NOVAMENTE");
        ValorDigitado = teclado.nextLine();
```

Mas para String é quase sempre necessário você utilizar essa sintaxe:

```
x.equals("valor desejado")
```

E como citado no exemplo que você colocou, para colocar o operador lógico de diferença (!=) na estrutura while com String, é necessário apenas colocar um "!" antes da sintaxe:

```
while(! nome.equals(nome2)) {

            System.out.println("DIGITE NOVAMENTE");
            nome = teclado.nextLine();
```

PS: Lembrando que String NÃO É um tipo primitivo, e sim uma classe, por isso tem essa sintaxe que se diferencia dos tipos int, float, double e char dentro de uma estrutura lógica.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui por este metodo

```
    String nome2 = "VITOR";
    
nome = teclado.nextLine();
        while(! nome.equals(nome2)) {
                System.out.println("DIGITE NOVAMENTE");
                
                nome = teclado.nextLine();
```

Mas se alguem souber o porque de não funcionar " != " agradeço :)